Parametros correctos para funcion aquireFingerprint(); del sensor dactilar Zkteco 4500
He estado trabajando para poder almacenar una huella digital mediante el sensor ZKTeco 4500. Este sensor viene con un SDK para implementarlo en java.
La función AcquireFingerprint() recibe 4 parámetros:

Un numero que identifica al sensor.
El tamaño de la imagen (alto * ancho) que se obtiene usando la
funcion getParameters
Un arreglo en bytes que contendrá el tamaño de la plantilla(2048
debe valer),
Un arreglo que contendrá la longitud de la plantilla de huella
dactilar devuelta por la función.

Sin embargo al correr mi aplicación recibo el error -8, fallo al capturar la imagen.
No se si haya personas que ya hayan usado este sensor que me puedan iluminar un poco. Muchas Gracias por leerme. Es la primera vez que trabajo con un sensor dactilar.
Este es mi código. Estoy trabajando con la librería ZKFingerReader.jar Venia en el SDK del sensor:
import com.zkteco.biometric.FingerprintSensorErrorCode; //Importacion de las librerias basicas a utilizar.

import com.zkteco.biometric.FingerprintSensorEx;
public class CapturaHuella {
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] bytes) { //Esta funcion se encarga de convertir un arreglo en bytes a tipo Int :)
    return ((bytes[0] & 0xFF)) |
            ((bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 8) |
            ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 16) |
            ((bytes[3] & 0xFF) << 24);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Aqui inicializamos el SDK:
    int encendido = FingerprintSensorEx.Init(); //--> Guardamos en una variable el retorno del metodo init()
    if (encendido != FingerprintSensorErrorCode.ZKFP_ERR_OK) {
        System.out.println("Error al inicializar el sensor: " + encendido); //-->Mostramos el tipo de error obtenido.
        return;
    }else{
        System.out.println("SDK inicializado correctamente!!"); //Si no obtenemos errores el SDK se ha inicializado! :)
    }

    // Abrir el dispositivo: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    long abertura = FingerprintSensorEx.OpenDevice(0); /*--> El metodo OpenDevice retorna 0 si no detecta el sensor.*/
    if (abertura == 0) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo abrir el dispositivo");
        return;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Dispositivo Listo para ser usado!!"); //
    }


    //--> Obtener datos del sensor: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Obtener el ancho
    int codancho = 1; // Código para obtener el ancho de la imagen
    int codalto = 2; // Código para obtener el alto de la imagen
    byte[] valueA = new byte[4];
    byte[] valueL = new byte[4];
    int[] size = new int[1];
    size[0] = 4;

    // Obtener el ancho
    int retancho = FingerprintSensorEx.GetParameters(abertura, codancho, valueA, size);
    if (retancho == 0) {
        int width = byteArrayToInt(valueA); //convertir array byte a tipo int.
        System.out.println("Ancho de la imagen: " + width + " pixeles");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error al obtener el ancho de la imagen: " + retancho);
    }

    // Obtener el largo de la imagen
    int retlargo = FingerprintSensorEx.GetParameters(abertura, codalto, valueL, size);
    if (retlargo == 0) {
        int height = byteArrayToInt(valueL); //convertir array byte a tipo int.
        System.out.println("Alto de la imagen: " + height + " pixeles");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error al obtener el ancho de la imagen: " + retlargo);
    }

    // Extraer una imagen y una plantilla de una huella: -----------------------------------------------------------


    // Calcular el tamaño del buffer de la imagen
   int imgSize = byteArrayToInt(valueA) * byteArrayToInt(valueL);
    //int imgSize = (280 * 360);
    byte[] imgBuffer = new byte[imgSize];
   // byte[] imgBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(imgSize).array();


    byte[] template = new byte[2048];
    int[] zise = new int[1];


    System.out.println("imgSize = " + imgSize );

    int rethuellita = FingerprintSensorEx.AcquireFingerprint(abertura,imgBuffer,template,size);

    if(rethuellita == 0){
        System.out.println("Huella capturada!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error al capturar huella: " + rethuellita);
    }

    // Cerrar el dispositivo y terminar :---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FingerprintSensorEx.CloseDevice(abertura); //Es muy importante cerrar el dispositivo para liberar recursos
    FingerprintSensorEx.Terminate(); //Y terminar la inicializacion del SDK para no tener errores inesperados :)
}

}
Adjunto la imagen de la funcion acquireFingerprint descrita en el SDK:

Esta es la Salida que obtengo:

y esta es la descripción de el error -8 que obtengo:

